# Как залить изменения на собственный репозиторий GitHub?

Tags: git, github, git-commit, репозиторий, git-репозиторий

У меня есть проект на GitHube, я скачал его к себе на компьютер, сделал несколько изменений и теперь хочу залить его обратно, вместе с этими изменениями, подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне это сделать.
P.S. Если подскажите, как это сделать из Intelij IDEA, буду очень благодарен

Comment: надеюсь скачали не `zip-ом`, но на всякий напишу (с консоли). 1) [`git clone`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone) 2) Изменяете 3) [`git add .`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add) 4) [`git commit -m "comment"`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit) 5) если разработчиков несколько [`git pull`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull) 6) [`git push`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push) это стандартный путь...а там есть еще куча настроек (я скидывал ссылки)...либо опишите более детально

Comment: Мало информации. Опишите как именно скачивали, форкали ли, ваш ли это репозиторий и в него ли надо изменения отправить или в новый. Заведён ли git на локальной версии проекта etc

Comment: ну и [`git` + `IntelliJ IDEA 2019.3`](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-git-integration.html)

Comment: @Виталий Шебаниц, а если zip-ом, это критично?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, скачивал zip-ом, репозиторий мой, изменения нужно направить в него, локальный git, вроде как, есть

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала нужно правильно скачать репозиторий. Нажмите на "Clone or download" [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Затем на "Open in Desktop" [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Установите GitHube себе на компьютер, а затем, с его помощью, скачайте репозиторий, теперь Вы можете редактировать его и заливать в то же место, откуда скачали, для этого нажмите галочку на панели управления в Intalij IDEA:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
После нажатия на галочку, появиться новое окно, в котором нужно будет выбрать команду "Commit and Push"